# Is anyone able to connect Shimano Di2 SM-BCR2 to Windows inside VirtualBox on Mac OSX?

Tags: software, shimano-di2

I have a Shimano Di2 with the SM-BCR2 charger. Unfortunately, Shimano's e-tube software only works with Windows. I installed it in VirtualBox virtual machine and connected the SM-BCR2 to my Apple Macbook. That was a no go.

I've changed the USB port settings from USB1 to USB2 and still nothing. Windows sees the USB port but the e-tube software does not.

I've read about people using VMWare Fusion and having some luck. But also read about people using VirtualBox and having luck. Not sure why it doesn't work for me.

Would I be better off just buying the d-fly unit (EW-WU101?) and connecting via Bluetooth through my iPhone?

Comment: Just an (obvious) note: using a different unit and different connection protocol might allow you reaching your goal, but it won't solve the original problem. USB device pass-through feature works with certain types of USB devices, but other hardware seems to connect unreliably through it.

Comment: Bluetooth will only work with the most recent Di2 battery. Alternatively you can get one of these very cheap Win notebooks, just for the work with Di2. Compare the expenses!

Comment: Is this a bike problem or a computer virtualisation problem ?

Comment: @Criggie it's a bike software problem, expect more as years go by and electronics on bikes become more mainstream. Same as what happened to cars.

Answer (score 6):

A late answer, but perhaps it helps some people. I used Vmware and not VirtualBox. However: I had to disconnect and connect the usb port in VMWare, even though Windows noticed that usb was connected to Windows. Shimano DI2 disagreed. A software reconnect of usb inside VMWare fixed this.
The solution suggested about D-Fly does not fix this. I have D-Fly installed, but I needed to update and connect to DI2 wired first before wireless was possible.
SM-BCR2 charger
BT-DN110 battery
EW-WU111 d-fly unit

Answer (score 2):

Using Parallels, I was able to get the system to recognize the USB connection by going to the Parallels menu, selecting Devices > Shimano BCR2, repeatedly. After about eight times (4x on/off switching between Mac and Windows), the e-tube s/w recognized the USB device.

Answer (score 1):

This is a stupid answer but you could install Windows onto a small partition on your Intel Mac using Boot Camp, and boot into this system only when necessary. Windows install cds are cheap enough and easy enough to make. You must already have one to use inside the VM.